# Google login without dialog

Tags: google-oauth, google-account

I wanted to know if the following workflow would be possible for an application I am developing. The backend is a python REST API and the frontend will use AngularJS.

What I would like to do is have a login page (requires email address + password) where depending on the email domain I would either try to do a Google login using OAuth or try authenticating using credentials stored in the database. Now as far as I can see to use Google Signin I have to have a dialog that comes up asking the user to login or select their account, but if the user has already entered their email and password on my login page I don't want them to have to enter it again when Google asks for it.

Thanks

Comment: Not possible. Google goes to great lengths to make sure that only humans can provide passwords, not apps acting on behalf of users.

Comment: How about something like this: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow

Comment: That still doesn't allow you to submit username/password credentials from your app.